# data-translate in data-bind not working

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am a newbie to knockout.js. I am having a problem. I am trying to translate the windowTitle in my `html` but I am getting an error. I can see the the window title when I do `console.log(data.windowTitle);` but i also get the following error in my console

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: missing : after property id; Bindings value: attr{data-translate:windowTitle}
```

That is how I am trying to do my job

```
<span data-bind="attr:{data-translate:windowTitle}"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data-translate` is not a valid javascript identifier. You need to wrap the identifier  name in quotes (`''`) to make it work

```
<span data-bind="attr:{ 'data-translate' :windowTitle}"></span>
```

See also in the documentation: [Applying attributes whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

Comment: What is now the error message? Are you sure that you have saved and refresed the page and this exact code `data-bind="attr:{ 'data-translate': windowTitle}"` is running?

Comment: solved the problem by doing `<span data-bind="attr:{'data-translate':$parent.tabSubHeading}">`

Comment: @Ahmed ok so adding the quotes around `'data-translate'` fixed the problem.